# Angular - How to optimize JSON.stringify?

Tags: json, angular

I have a service in my Angular app that gets JSON data from an API.

This API, sometimes, returns more than 400 records (JSON Objects).

When I access the endpoint directly from my browser, it takes a little (about 5 seconds) time to fill all the page with the JSON. After this, I can see everything without any issue.

But, I need to put this returned JSON in a HTML `code` tag because the user wants to see the JSON. He doesn't want to see in a table, he wants the JSON.

I'm using the following code to achieve this:

HTML:

```
<div>                   
    <pre>
       <code [highlight]="lastData" [lineNumbers]="true"></code>
    </pre>            
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
this.myService.getLastData(this.myObject)
        .subscribe(json => this.lastData= JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4))
```

It does work!

But, when the returned JSON is big, it takes a lot of time to renderize on the screen, and sometimes it simply doesn't renderize! The browser freezes and the only way to get back to the page is by reopening it.

Please, is there something that I can do to optmize this process?

Thank you

Comment: An easy solution would be for the server to return a prettified JSON. That would prevent the whole parsing + stringify on the client-side

Answer (score 0):

Can you please implement server side pagination if you have huge data for display. Otherwise that may affect the performance of the application.